# Writing DRY code with terraform for loop?

Tags: terraform

I am very new to terraform and had a task dropped upon me to create 2 AWS KMS keys.
So I am doing this:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "ebs_encryption_key" {
  description              = "EBS encryption key"
  ... omitted for brevity ...

  tags = merge(map(
        "Name", format("%s-ebs-encryption-key", var.name_prefix),
        "component", "kms",
        "dataclassification","low",
        ), var.extra_tags)
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "ebs_encryption_key" {
  name                 = format("alias/%s-ebs-encryption-key", var.name_prefix)
  target_key_id        = aws_kms_key.ebs_encryption_key.key_id
}

# Repeated code!
resource "aws_kms_key" "rds_encryption_key" {
  description              = "RDS encryption key"
  ... omitted for brevity ...

  tags = merge(map(
        "Name", format("%s-rds-encryption-key", var.name_prefix),
        "component", "kms",
        "dataclassification","low",
        ), var.extra_tags)
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "rds_encryption_key" {
  name                 = format("alias/%s-rds-encryption-key", var.name_prefix)
  target_key_id        = "${aws_kms_key.rds_encryption_key.key_id}"
}
```

As you can see the only difference between the two blocks of code is "ebs" and "rds"?
How could I use a for loop to avoid repeating the code blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it could be a candidate for a small module that encapsulates the details of declaring a key and an associated alias, since a key and an alias are typically declared together in your system.

The module itself would look something like this:

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}

variable "description" {
  type = string
}

variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "main" {
  description = var.description
  # ...

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "main" {
  name          = "alias/${var.name}"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.main.key_id
}

output "key_id" {
  value = aws_kms_key.main.key_id
}

output "alias_name" {
  value = aws_kms_alias.main.name
}
```

(As written here this module feels a little silly because there's not really much here that isn't derived only from the variables, but I'm assuming that the interesting stuff you want to avoid repeating is in "omitted for brevity" in your example, which would go in place of `# ...` in my example.)

Your calling module can then include a `module` block that uses `for_each` to create two instances of the module, systematically setting the arguments to populate its input variables:

```
module "kms_key" {
  for_each = {
    kms = "KMS"
    ebs = "EBS"
  }

  name        = "${var.name_prefix}-${each.key}-encryption-key"
  description = "${each.value} Encryption Key"
  tags = merge(
    var.extra_tags,
    {
      Name               = "${var.name_prefix}-${each.key}-encryption-key"
      component          = "kms"
      dataclassification = "low"
    },
  )
}
```

Since the `for_each` map here has the keys `kms` and `ebs`, the result of this will be to declare resource instances which should have the following addresses in the plan:

- `module.kms_key["kms"].aws_kms_key.main`
- `module.kms_key["kms"].aws_kms_alias.main`
- `module.kms_key["ebs"].aws_kms_key.main`
- `module.kms_key["ebs"].aws_kms_alias.main`

Since they are identified by the map keys, you can add new keys to that map in future to create new key/alias pairs without disturbing the existing ones.

If you need to use the key IDs or alias names elsewhere in your calling module then you can access them via the outputs exposed in `module.kms_key` elsewhere in that calling module:

- `module.kms_key["kms"].key_id`
- `module.kms_key["kms"].alias_name`
- `module.kms_key["ebs"].key_id`
- `module.kms_key["ebs"].alias_name`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just one more question.  I need the ebs key to be outputted from the module to passed as a parameter to another module.  What would the "output" clause look like?